# Regarding the zero internal electric field in a conductor (electrostatic case)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, conductors

Let's say we have a homogenous electric field in the $z$-direction. For computational simplicity let's say we have a thin sheet of metal covering entire the $x$-$y$ plane. The answer here is straight forward.

Let us now place a second sheet just below the first with the same orientation.
The solution to the electrical field here is also straight forward.
If the two planes are now electrically connected by say a single wire, I'm not so sure.

It appears there are two degenerate charge distributions that would zero out the internal fields, one where nothing changes by connecting the wire, and one where the top surface of the top plane acquires a surface charge density and the bottom surface of the bottom plate acquires an equal opposite charge density. I wager thermodynamics holds the answer.
This is the simplest case, but I was thinking of degenerate charge distributions in general.

EDIT:
My thoughts were that the latter distribution is correct, as any connecting wire would have to also have a zero electric field within it, if you scale this to several more planes with varying connections between them, it's not so clear, so I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Has your question something to do with the phenomenon that electrons somehow are without their electric field in atoms? They are sitting side by side around the nucleus, but their electric fields seem not to exist while they are there. For metals there are surface electrons but they aren't flying away, what they have to do due to the repulsion of their electric fields.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Yes, they are definitely related. I'm interested in exciting transitions between general states like this. Note they are at different energy levels (my reason for thinking the latter distribution may be the correct one), and for other geometries, there will be many more than two such states.

Comment: R.Rankin During my researches I came to the conclusion that electrons loose their electric field in the atom bond and the distribution around the nucleus follows the possible arrangement of their magnetic dipole moments. See my elaborations about [One-dimensional structures in space and Distribution of magnetic dipole moments of electrons in atoms](https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler). It's not mainstream but elegant.